# Apply over dataframe with lists in columns

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe one column contains lists of elements and I would like to call some function over every element of every list

My problem is similar to that:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'x':[*range(1,5,1)],
                    'y':[[*range(x*10,100,10)] for x in range(4)]})
data
    x   y
0   1   [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
1   2   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
2   3   [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
3   4   [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

data['y'] = data.y.apply(float)
```

So I want to get

```
data
    x   y
0   1   [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
1   2   [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
2   3   [20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
3   4   [30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
```

In this example I want to call `float` function on every element of every list of `y` - can I do this without loops and `iterrows` things? Maybe something like `.apply.apply(float)`?

Comment: `apply` is (almost) a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.array`:

```
import numpy as np

data['y'] = data.y.apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=float).tolist())
print(data)

# Output:
   x                                                  y
0  1  [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0...
1  2  [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80....
2  3   [20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
3  4         [30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0]
```

**OR**

Use a comprehension:

```
data['y'] = data.y.apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
```

A more bit complicated way:

```
data['y'] = data.explode('y').astype({'y': float}) \
                .groupby('x')['y'].agg(list).values
```

Comment: yes, the list comprehension seems to work. The  `np.array`  would solve that problem, but I'm strugling with "special" functions that I want to call on elements in those lists, so `np.array` or `astype` will not work in my main problem which is text analysis :/

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer a list comprehension, when possible - as proposed above.

Another approach could be using `map`:

```
data["y"] = data["y"].apply(lambda x:list(map(float,x)))
```